# Why does timerfd_settime fail with EBADF when called with valid fd from timerfd_create?

Tags: c, linux

I have a function that creates a timerfd timer, but sometimes the `timerfd_settime` returns with EBADF (Bad file descriptor). I cannot fathom a scenario where `timerfd_create` returns a valid file descriptor, which then fails when immediately called with `timerfd_settime`.

I use this function with an epoll event loop, and sometimes, this function will return a valid fd, only to have `epoll_ctl` fail with EBADF when adding the timer fd. I assume that if I understand why `timerfd_settime` sometimes fail, it will illuminate the epoll fail as well.

```
static inline int create_timer(uint32_t interval_ms, uint32_t start_ms)
{
    struct itimerspec its = {{0}};
    int fd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0);

    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("timerfd_create");
        return -1;
    }

    its.it_interval = timespec_ns((int64_t)(interval_ms) * NSEC_PER_MSEC);

    if (start_ms)
        its.it_value = timespec_ns((int64_t)(start_ms) * NSEC_PER_MSEC);
    else
        its.it_value.tv_nsec = 1;

    if (timerfd_settime(fd, 0, &its, NULL) < 0) {
       perror("timerfd_settime");
       close(fd);
       return -1;
   }

   return fd;
}
```

It is used in a multi threaded "curl_multi_socket" application. There are multiple worker threads, that each needs to download many files and parse them, often. Each thread has its own epoll-loop. Inter-thread communication is handled through the use of unix sockets.

The function is used to set the timeouts for the CURLs timerfunc callback:

```
static int fetch_timerfunc(CURLM *curlm, long timeout_ms, void *ctx)
{
    struct fetch *cm = (struct fetch*) ctx;
    struct epoll_event ev = {};

    // Cancel previous timeout, if any
    if (cm->timer_fd > 0) {
        close(cm->timer_fd);
        cm->timer_fd = 0;
    }

    if (timeout_ms < 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    cm->timer_fd = create_timer(0, timeout_ms);
    if (cm->timer_fd < 0) {
        perror("fetch_timerfunc: create_timer");
        return cm->timer_fd;
    }

    ev.events = EPOLLIN;
    ev.data.fd = CURL_SOCKET_TIMEOUT;

    if (epoll_ctl(cm->epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, cm->timer_fd, &ev) < 0) {
        if (!exiting) {
            perror("fetch_timerfunc: epoll_ctl");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this program have multiple threads?

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with the code you posted. Unlesss you show a full [MCVE] I doubt anyone can help you. How do you use `epoll_ctl`? What is `timespec_ns`? And, if you have other threads, do they call `close`?

Comment: @zwol It does have multiple threads, but each thread has its own epoll loop, and does not share any global data. There are 50 worker threads that communicate with a controller thread over unix sockets.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yeah I figured as much, not been able to reproduce this effect outside the program running. `timespec_ns` is a helper function:
`return (struct timespec) {(time_t) (ns / NSEC_PER_SEC), (long) (ns % NSEC_PER_SEC)};`

Comment: @Telc I'm wondering if one of the other threads may be calling close() on an fd that has already been closed and then its number has been reused for the timer.

Comment: `It does have multiple threads` try like `strace -ff -e close,timerfd_open` and others and catch if you can spot if one thread does `timerfd_open` and then some other does `close()` on the same fd right after. And, add a `close` error handler, maybe there's EBADFD there to. But definitely concentrate on creating reproducible [MCVE] within your program.

Answer (score 0):

@KamilCuk is right. A bug in another place caused one thread to sometimes close fd 0 many times in quick succession. This meant that `timerfd_create` sometimes returned 0 as its assigned fd, and that got immediately closed in the buggy thread before the call to `timerfd_settime`.